# Problem with mouseListener on JPanel

Tags: java, mouse, listener

I have problem with mouseListener in JPanel.
I add JLabel which contain image(size 600 x 600) on JPanel, and I add mouseListener for the JPanel.

Everytimes I click on the image, the image should change to another image, and this is working fine. However, the problem is that, only if I click on the right side or at the center of the image, then the image will change to another image. The image doesn't change when I click on the top or on the left side. This make me confused. I want the image to change to another image when I click everywhere within the image display.

```
private final int SECOND= 1;
private final int FIRST = 0;
int imageCounter = 0;

JLabel picture;
JPanel panel;

...

private mainLayout () {
  GridBagLayout m = new GridBagLayout();
  Container c = (Container)getContentPane();
  GridBagConstraints con;
  c.setLayout (m);

  picture = new JLabel();
  picture.setIcon(getImages(myImage.get(imageCounter).get(FIRST)));  //first Image

  panel = new JPanel();     
  con = new GridBagConstraints();
  con.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
  con.gridy = 1; con.gridx = 0;     
  m.setConstraints(panel, con);
  c.add(panel);
  panel.add(picture); //add the pictures

  panel.addMouseListener(l);
  ....
}

MouseListener l = new MouseAdapter(){
  public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) 
  {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    if((panel.getBounds().contains(p))
       picture.setIcon(getImages(myImage.get(imageCounter).get(SECOND)));
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the listener to the JLabel instead of JPanel?

Comment: Thanks so much nandokakimoto...thats solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks as if it might be in this unnecessary code:

```
Point p = e.getPoint();
if((panel.getBounds().contains(p))
```

The mouse listener is on the panel, so the mouse coordinates will be relative to the panel top left. `panel.getBounds()` gets the bounds of the panel relative to whatever its parent container is.

It's worth noting the mouse event behave very strangely. They "bubble up" until they hit a component with a mouse listener attached. So, adding a mouse listener actually changes the behaviour of a component. Adding the listener to a parent will potentially miss events depending upon the exact way the component is set up (which may change arbitrarily). There are a number of ways around this, none of them good.

Answer (score 2):

The likely problem you have is the same I have encountered, that your event is getting gobbled up in your hierarchy as a previous poster implied.  In reference to camickr's reply, it really doesn't matter if you extend `JPanel` or `JLabel` as long as you're aware of the consequences.  `JPanel` offers you a lot more capability and has many useful things already built into it.  But let's take the simple example where you have the following:

A `JFrame` that contains a `JPanel`, call it's `JParent`.  `JParent` has a set of mouse listeners dedicated to it.

`JParent` contains a child `JPanel` that's added to its components, called `JChild`.  `JChild` also has its own set of mouse listeners.

What happened when you click on an area that is not occupied by `JChild`?  You get the response of `JParent`'s listeners.  If you click in an area with `JChild` visible, only `JChild`'s mouse events will fire.

So be very careful in debugging as Java's swing may have different behavior than you may be used to from other implementations of drawing simple forms/GUIs.  Events are basically one-shot and the lowest level component gets first dibs.  If you try to fire the parent's events anyway, your x/y coords will be based on the child and not the parent.  I'm still trying to come up with a good work around myself because I need access specifically to the parent to move an object elsewhere.

The best I can think of that isn't a mess to debug/think about are these two ideas:
a) have each of your individual components contain their own exclusive set of events and try to prevent the 'bubbling up' effect from coming into play.
b) handle all events on the parent

I'd prefer a as it avoids nasty things such as checking component classes just to figure out what kind of reaction you want (i.e. things like what kind of right-click menu to show).

Edit:  So you can handle this either way I've discovered.  You can use the dispatchEvent message to forward the events back upward the chain.  In my case I have to gobble up the first event (or alter it) and send the x-y positions as if they are relative to the parent (using offsets).  I'd say the better way to do it is through forwarding because then all your individual components can be encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that you are actually clicking? The mouse click event only fires if the mouse is pressed and released in the exact same spot. If your mouse is moving even minimally while you are clicking, the event won't be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why are you using a JLabel to display an image? You may be better off writing an ImagePanel class that extends JPanel and overrides the paint() method to do your own drawing. Then you can attach MouseListeners right to the panel.

Comment: -1 Why would you create a custom component and do custom painting when this fuctionality is built into the a JLabel already? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi Seth, I used the JLabel to display the image in jpg format.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much control you want over the drawing. Fair point though.